# Flask application not giving POST request from the browser URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, http-post, flash-message

I have written an Flask application using POST Method in Python3. Whenever I hit the URL, on the command prompt, I see `GET` method is called.
Here is the application:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request    
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api/v1.0/qanda/', methods=['POST'])
def people_api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.data.get('text', '')

        if text is None:
           make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Missing text parameter'}), 400)
    return text
app.run()
```

Whenever I hit the url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/qanda/?text=ggg
```

I see on the command line as:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2017 09:33:15] "GET /api/v1.0/qanda/?text=ggg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2017 09:33:22] "GET /api/v1.0/qanda/?text=ggg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But I want to use only the post method while hitting the URL. I do not know why the GET method is coming int play. Kindly, let me know how I can using the `POST` method instead of `GET` method while hitting the URL through browser.

Comment: Chrome plugin for creating post request (and many others, such as Postman) are nice. A form in html as `<form method="post" ... >` also works

Comment: While hitting URL through browser it will be always send GET request to your server by browser. No way you can send POST request by this approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a POST request through the address bar. You'll have to use JavaScript or submit a form with the method='post'.

A couple examples:

Form:

```
<form method='post' action='your url'>
  <input name='name' type='text'>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

JavaScript(with jQuery):

```
$.post({'your': 'data'})
```

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: But that's not the address bar. That's a plugin. Unless I misunderstand what it's doing.

Comment: @CoryMadden Yes you are write. I am not looking for application, but for a solution for address bar

Comment: A html post request doesn't even put args in the url

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a post call to a url from browser address bar. You can use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) tool. It's very easy to make requests with this tool, supports all request methods and Authorization headers.

Or simply you can use python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) module to make request

```
Import requests

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post/', data = {'key':'value'})
```